# Не создается папка node_modules, из-за чего я не могу создать новый проект на angular

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

Сначала была проблема **Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near**, которая решилась с помощью команд **npm cache clear --force** и **npm cache verify**. Потом я через cmd, с правами админа, указываю папку, где я хочу создать новый проект на Angular, и запускаю команду **npm init**, ставлю там дефолтные настройки (т.е. просто жму Enter), а потом команду **npm install -g @angular/cli**. Результат на картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В указанной папке файл paskage.json есть, а папка node_modules - отсутствует. При попытке создать новый проект - процесс зависает. Я пробовал удалять папки npm и npm-cache из C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming, пробовал переустанавливать Node - ничего не помогло. Может я чего-то не понимаю. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, главное чтобы ответ был подробный.

Comment: Командой npm install -g вы устанавливаете пакет глобально (в вашем случае @angular/cli). После этого вам необходимо запустить команду npm install, чтобы на основе файла package.json локально подтянулись все зависимости (в папку node_modules в директории проекта).

Comment: Сделал npm install в папку проекта, папка node_modules не появилась

Comment: Какая-то ошибка или команда прошла нормально? package.json не пустой?

Comment: Нет, не пустой, cmd говорит, что команды проходят нормально

Comment: После исполнения npm install, появился файл paskage-lock.json

Comment: Если вам нужен angular проект, удалите текущую папку проекта и запустите ng new.

Comment: Там нет папки проекта, вот именно по указанному адресу я хочу ее поставить. При выполнении команды ng new процесс зависает, я это писал

Comment: Судя по фото, вы работали только с npm. Запустите ng new и покажите ошибки. А вначале ng version, покажет ли версию.

Comment: Запустил ng version - Angular CLI    10.0.1, Node      12.18.1, @angular-devkit/architect 0.1000.1, @angular-devkit/core   10.0.1, @angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.1, @schematics/angular   10.0.1, @schematics/update           0.1000.1, rxjs   6.5.5. И я не знаю почему, но теперь npm install -g @angular/cli && ng new myApp - работает нормально, и папка node_modules появляется, проект запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось создать проект, следуя инструкциям с https://metanit.com/web/angular2/1.1.php. Там предварительно создается package.json с содержимым, которое я раньше не прописывал. Возможно проблема была именно в этом, но точно я не знаю. Успешно появилась папка node_modules и проект запустился. После этого получилась выполнить npm install -g @angular/cli && ng new myApp и опять же я не знаю почему раньше процесс зависал.

Comment: Вообще, есть сайт angular.io, и там достаточно подробно написано, как начать.
Сначала npm install -g @angular/cli, для глобальной установки angular.
Потом используем команду ng:
ng new my-app,
cd my-app,
ng serve --open

Comment: Именно с него я и начал